# How to prevent to direct link access in Code igniter

Tags: codeigniter

How to prevent to direct link access in Code igniter

E.g.

http://localhost/myapp/admin/displayUser

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in authentication library within CodeIgniter, although there are many well developed third party ones. My preference is for Ion Auth - http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/.

However if you are simply referring to preventing access to some "private" controller methods,  you should add an underscore to the beginning of the method name - this will mean it is not accessible via a url, only via other controller methods:

```
function _myprivatemethod() {

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a library as `authenticate.php` having following code into it and add that library in `autoload.php`

```
class Authenticate
{
    function Authenticate()
    {
        $CI = & get_instance(); 
        if ($CI->session->userdata('USERID') == "")
        {
            $redirectlink = 'contoller function path to your login page';
            redirect($redirectlink);   
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This my not help you but it might help someone else.

I did it by creating a hook that checks if the user is logged in . If they are not it redirects them to the home login controller.

```
if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        redirect('user/login');
}
```

If you create a Auth_Controller that extends CI Controller then instead of extending CI Controller you can make all your apps extend your new Auth_Controller so they always redirect if the user is not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        redirect('user/login');
}
```

this will perfectly work..
just remember to load the session library as well.

```
$this->load->library('session');
```